# ASP.NET MVC2 Areas/Administration and Working it all together

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2

I am new to asp.net mvc in general and have yet to build a fully functional application. The main reason for this is I couldn't get my head around building administration areas.

I am now looking at MVC2 and have noticed this new feature called areas, I have created a sample application with an area called Announcements (essentially a blog post) does anyone know where a simple example may exist or could you provide one to do the following:

- Show a working Admin area for Posts/Announcements.
- Show how to display the posts/announcements to the public.

I assume these concepts are simple enough to do and I am probably struggling because I am looking at it from a web forms way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are struggling with some of the basic concepts of MVC. [Scott Hanselman's NerdDinner tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/03/10/free-asp-net-mvc-ebook-tutorial.aspx) would probably be very beneficial to you. It goes over the fundamentals. The tutorial is for MVC 1, so "Areas" are not explained, but once you understand the basic MVC concepts "Areas" should come naturally.